# Should normal methods inside of an async function be also async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core

I have an api end point that is async and then I'm awaiting fetch from database. If I want to use a helper method after the fetching is done of type like  calculate something, does it have to be async aswell(it does not call any database, beside using the data that was fetched and makes some calculations)

If it has to be async, how do I do force things to be async then?
Like this?

```
    await Task.Run(() => {
       Calculate();
    });
```

Or do I just leave it sync instead.

```
var numbers = await repo.Numbers.ToListAsync();
Calculate(numbers);
```

Comment: it is normal and expected to make use of sync code inside async regions; it is actually required for some of the new things in the upcoming "pipelines" IO API, since the framework is async, but many of the key primitives are `ref struct`, so can only be used from synchronous code. This would work just like your example

Answer (score 4):

Leave it synchronous if it isn't doing file or database I/O, or other potentially blocking operations.

Think about it this way: if what you ask were true, the entire .NET API would be async, there's no difference between your proposed `Calculate` example and something like `Int32.TryParse` or any other random API call.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in your example is not ideal.

If your underlying call (**Calculate** in this case) is synchronous, and there are no other asynchronous operation calls within your API, then there is no point in marking your API as "asynchronous", unless you have to satisfy a contract.

On the side note, though, data retrieval is actually an IO operation, and it should be asynchronous. Instead of wrapping that IO logic in a synchronous "Calculate" method, I'd recommend updating it to be async (you can follow a convention and name it **CalculateAsync** then). That will allow you to eliminate the Task.Run call as it'll be unnecessary.

To generalize this, an API should be async, if it consumes asynchronous logic. Otherwise - it should be synchronous.